# защита листов в Googlesheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Я создала таблицу в Googlesheets. У  меня есть 6 листов, нужно сделать так чтобы лист был заблокирован даже для просмотра. Допустим 2 листа доступны только для сотрудников, а все листы включая эти два листа директору. Обязательно то, чтобы листы которые принадлежат директору никто не мог увидеть, но все должно находится в одном файле, но с разным доступом. Доступ ограничивала, но все могут просматривать файлы, но не могут редактировать, надо сделать так, чтобы и просматривать тоже не могли. Что делать, как скрыть листы от других людей?

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=ru

Comment: когда скрываешь листы, и тот для кого они доступны их открывает, они снова становятся видимыми.

Answer (score 0):

Защита листов в смысле "чтоб никто не смог получить доступ" невозможна.

Правила защиты листов и диапазонов распространяются внутри Таблицы. Поэтому, все, кто знают id вашей Таблицы и могут ее хотя бы читать, смогут получить доступ и к остальным данным.

Вам необходимо пересмотреть ваш бизнес-процесс в отношении этих данных.